# Issue with import myplot as plt2

Tags: python, matplotlib, import

I am going to apply decision tree to my dataset and plot decision boudaries of decision of tree. I am using python 3.5 in anaconda. at the first line i am doing the code below but i got this error: "No module named myplot"
i have already installed matplotlib library but again i am facing the error
Will be grateful if anyone can help me with it?

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import matplotlib.pyplot as pltdefplot_decision_regions
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
import myplot as plt2
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_decision_regions
```

Comment: Did you mean `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt2`?

Answer (score 1):

You can take the error message seriously: It tells you that there is no module named `myplot`.

The question now is, should there be one?! Seen from the outside with no information about your system etc. I would say that the error is correct. I do not know of any official released module with that name.

It may well be that you created a module of that name by yourself. In this case you need to make sure that this module is available in the path where python looks for modules.

Otherwise you need to think about which module you really wanted to import instead of the non-existent `myplot`.

Appart from that it would make sense to sort your imports a bit and not import the same modules under different names more than once.

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, export_graphviz
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import numpy as np
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_decision_regions
```